# CLLocationDistance returns totally wrong values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocation, cllocationdistance

I am using this function to get the distance from one CLLocation to another

here venue.lat is NSNumber

```
GeoAddress *address = [[GeoAddress new] init];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[venue.lat doubleValue];
coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[venue.lng doubleValue];

address.latlng = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude: coord.longitude];

if (curUserLocation.coordinate.latitude){
    address.distance = [address.latlng distanceFromLocation:curUserLocation];
    NSLog(@" DISTANCE %f", address.distance);
    NSLog(@" LOC1 %f lat %f lng", address.latlng.coordinate.latitude, address.latlng.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@" ME %f lat %f lng", curUserLocation.coordinate.latitude, curUserLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

This is Geoaddress:

```
//  GeoAddress.h
@interface GeoAddress : NSObject
{        
    CLLocation * latlng;
   CLLocationDistance  distance;
}
@property  CLLocationDistance  distance;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  CLLocation * latlng;

//  GeoAddress.m
#import "GeoAddress.h"

@implementation GeoAddress
@synthesize distance;
@synthesize  latlng;
```

This is the log:

```
DISTANCE 15106456.105786
LOC1 -73.986357 lat 40.702645 lng
ME 40.702082 lat -73.984775 lng
```

The numbers are completely off actual distance is ~0.17 km

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: In the simulator I get a wrong distance too, I guess there is a default position returned just because it's not a real device.

Comment: I think the latitude and longitude for LOC1 is backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have lines that say:

```
coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[venue.lat doubleValue];
coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[venue.lng doubleValue];
```

Obviously that should be:

```
coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[venue.lng doubleValue];
coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[venue.lat doubleValue];
```

Comment: oh wow.. thank you. can't believe I just tried to convert them via the actual formula.

Comment: Thanks, this just clued me in what I was doing wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

Where you set `coord` from `venue`, the latitude and longitude are being assigned backwards.

This gives you the unexpected distance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your output:

```
LOC1 -73.986357 lat 40.702645 lng
ME 40.702082 lat -73.984775 lng
```

You exchanged lat and long in ME